# css dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create level 2 drop-drop down. I came bit close and stucked. Please assist me to complete it.

Here is the **[JsBin](http://jsbin.com/eyarap/7/edit)**

```
 li{list-style:none;line-height:30px;}
 a{text-decoration:none;color:#c3c3c3;font-family:consolas;width:100%;}
 a:hover{color:white;}

 li{padding:5px;background-color:#5970B2;}

 /*li*/a:hover{background-color:grey;}
 ul#sddm{position:relative;}

 ul#sddm ul{display:none;}

 ul#sddm>li{float:left;}

 ul#sddm>li:hover>ul 
 {white-space: nowrap;display:block;position:absolute;margin:0;padding:0;}


 ul#sddm ul li:hover ul
 {white-space: nowrap;display:block;margin-left:150px;
   position:absolute;margin-top:0;padding:0;}

 ul#sddm ul li:hover ul>li{}
```

It will be good for me, if someone explain what I was doing wrong..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can solve the issue but you have written inline css so its taking time

Comment: @HappySingh ok I can wait...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fiddle for demo http://jsfiddle.net/dineshswami/4pLt3/1/

Changes in css:

```
a{text-decoration:none;color:#c3c3c3;font-family:consolas; display:block;padding:2px;}

ul#sddm>li{float:left; position:relative;}

ul#sddm ul li:hover ul{white-space: nowrap;display:block;margin-left:150px;position:absolute;margin-top:0;padding:0;left:-2px;margin-top:-39px;}
```

**Changes in html:** I removed inline css

Problem: The problem was you was forcing the elements by giving inline css so they was not align properly where they want to be. Little changes in position where you mention absolute. So i change the left and top value you can see in css above.

As i mentioned the problem above, let me explain in detail:

1. To expand the the `<a>` tag to the entire width of `<li>` tag i just removed the css `width: 100%;` and add new css rules `display:block;padding:2px;`
2. To adjust the first drop down width i removed the entire inline css from html. so all elements are able to take entire width on basis of text.
3. To adjust the second level drop down i set the top and left properties to `left:-2px;margin-top:-39px;` Why i did this because there was a gap between in first level drop down and second level and margin-top to -39px because you have given line-height:30px; which is increasing the height so i have set the margin-top.

Comment: ya sure i m removing html from here but will keep css other wise stackoverflow will not allow to save just only fiddle.

Comment: glad to help your problem. If any thing else required you can ask. If my answer is right please mark it right. Thnks

Comment: +1 one small problem.. the element `a` is not stretching as the `li` is..  I mean `a` should cover `li`.

Comment: see the updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/dineshswami/4pLt3/3/ still any changes required?

Comment: Or you mean to say the the <a> tag should cover entire <li> tag space?

Comment: no thanks.. but if you update the post too will be good for me to understand how you did that :). thanks again.

Comment: Arghhhh the main reason was because of inline css. I didnt get it when you first commented.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change top and left properties to adjust
I have edited [jsdin](http://jsbin.com/eyarap/14/)